# How to infer data type for custom useFetch hook?

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to create a useFetch hook and the thing is that any object / array can come as data, is it possible to somehow type this so as not to specify any?

**Example**

```
  function useRequest(url: string, method: Method, data: any) {
  const [response, setResponse] = useState<any>(undefined)
  const [isLoading, setIsLoading] = useState<boolean>(false)
  const [error, setError] = useState<AxiosError | undefined>(undefined)

  const requestNow = async () => {
    setIsLoading(true)
    try {
      const response = await apiClient.post(url, data)
      .....
```

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

If you want to ensure that, as long as `data` has certain properties, you don't care about its actual type, you can use the `extends` keyword in TS.

Take a look at this example:

```
type WithName = { name: string };

function useRequest<T extends WithName>(url: string, method: Method, data: T) {
  // Rest of the code
}
```

Check this [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA6glsAFgOQIYFtoF4oG8B2GEAXFAM7ABOc+A5gL4DcAsAFCiRQCyESA9gBMoOVPhCMoAeklQAggIE1aUJHDJQAVgFcKKvlDCoAxnABmIKABUAymzamt+I8Dh98UHRABKEAI5aICgAeSygIAA9gCHwBdXgkNEwAPgAKLUoAG1IKajoAGihMfgFSHmKCgVRgVFJLAEo8NigpGR9dPlMVRGgjQQg2ejtWIwzUMnUABQhKMjdG1mawLQAjDLgjKEJMbKolFlYmgxW1jd78HK1nPkoUrZJyXboG3EPm1TIAOjvhTaJ95sGrEBbDOugEWgE2HmzTupAA5LIMhE4XlDqhaPcAMwAJgGQ2kUAAaqg1gI2J4fP5AsAUnDZpgAKqZFFQOEs3C-basxHIqD0Or7Cl+AIUWn0iBMjIstkFfAQADuUCmMzctJ54ThdQF5LI3mF1LFfEZzIKMqg4Mh2oOrAJAEl8AA3ElwMmsIVU0V0o0Sk2s9mbPjARL3BFIjV8q3ukU0r3GqWm9n8wW6ynRw1x6UsuWKgAiVQgKS1yb1Hpj4slmYKAEZsZiBUA) for examples.

Comment: I just want to be sure that data that I pass to this hook infered properly like 

useRequest('someUrl', { name: 'Alex' })

Comment: Ah! My bad, I thought you meant to have type safety on the HTTP response. Let me update my answer.

Comment: But what if we don't have name field hm

Comment: What format do you expect your data to take, then? It is not clear in your question so I based my answer in your comment.